# Hibernate pagination of sorted data with joins

Tags: java, hibernate, pagination

We currently are investigating ways to speed up our applications and a large part of that is related to a list (actually a table) of entities.

**Parameters and requirements**

The parameters and requirements for that list are the following (I'll try to only mention relevant ones here):

- There can be up to 500,000 rows/entities in the list.
- Only a couple of those are displayed at a time, we'll be using pagination here.
- The user is able to select which columns are to be displayed in the list (so we can't provide a single "static" query).
- Most of those list columns are sortable and/or filterable.
- The entities have a couple of to-many relations which also provide some of the list columns.
- Some of those list columns can contain multiple values (those are displayed as a list inside a single cell)
- Any updates to the data originating from the current user's actions (e.g. editing, uploads etc.) should be reflected in the list as fast as possible (i.e. "immeditately")

To make the model a bit clearer consider the following simplified entity (as in JPA) model:

```
class Car {
  String manufacturer;
  String model;
  Date dateOfProduction;
  List<TyreSize> allowedTyreSizes;
  Set<Date> inspectionDates;
}
```

Please don't try to put too much meaning into that model since it's just meant to illustrate the problem (our data is different and much more complex).

A "complete" list of cars could then look like this:

```
+==============+=======+=======+===============+=============+
| Manufacturer | Model | Prod. | Allowed Tyres | Inspections |
+==============+=======+=======+===============+=============+
| BMW          | 320d  |01/2016| - 225/40 R18  | - 01/07/16  |
|              |       |       | - 225/45 R17  | - 13/12/16  |
+--------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+
| Toyota       | Camry |09/2016| - 185/70 R13  | - 31/12/16  |
+--------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+
```

Since the user can select the columns to be displayed at runtime we're building the necessary queries dynamically. That's all working quite well so far.

**Basic problem**

The problem we're having is performance when sorting and filtering are involved: Our current approach is to load all data necessary to sort and filter into memory, do the sorting and filtering there and then keep a list of sorted ids and page on those. We are aware that this is somewhat slow but so far performance was good enough to satisfy our management. Things have changed though since we now have more data to operate on and performance requirements have gone up.

Thus we're investigating ways to improve sorting and filtering of all that data adn while we're currently following the approach of doing it on the database I'll still ask this (side) question:

- How would pagination on a large number of rows with dynamic columns and potentially multiple values per cell be best approached?

Currently we're using Postgresql and would like to keep using it if possible but if a different storage would be far better suited we'd at least check that out.

**Current approach and question(s)** <sub>(at the bottom)</sub>

As described above we're currently trying to have the database sort, filter and paginate our data. It would be ok to use 2 queries: one for getting the row ids for the current page and one to actually load the data for those rows.

Since the challenge is the first query I'll concentrate on that:

AFAIK we could do something like this in SQL (using the car example above):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM (
  SELECT id, ... FROM car c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN allowedtyresizes ats ON c.id = ats.car_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tyresizes ts ON ts.id = ats.tyresize_id
    ... //additional joins if required
    ORDER BY ... //apply any user-defined sorts
    WHERE ... //apply any user-defined filters (or maybe put them into the joins)
  )
  OFFSET ... //page offset
  LIMIT ...  //page size
```

In theory this query (it might not be entirely correct though) should provide the result we need to identify which rows to load for the current page.

Since we're using Hibernate (5.2 atm) we'd like to use HQL or Criteria to achieve that. However it seems as if Hibernate doesn't support selecting from a select statement like above and thus this might not be a viable approach. If we'd have to fall back to native SQL or an entirely different approach so be it, but we'd prefer to make it work with the infrastructure that's currently in place.

So the questions are:

- Does Hibernate 5.x support something like a "select from select"?
- How could pagination using Hibernate be done when sorting and filtering has to be done on to-many relations, i.e. where a single join could result in duplicate rows?

Comment: You run SQL query using HQL by passing you query into it as String

Comment: @GauravSrivastav Yes we know how to execute a SQL query and if there's no better approach we'll be using that. However, since the queries could become quite complex and are created dynamically we'd rather like not having to access the mapping information of our entities to extract the information necessary for building such a query - not if Hibernate already provides something we could use.

Comment: How complex is your model? You would probably get the best performance by using database view(s) and binding the entities against them. The bad thing is that you'd need to hand-write the database view (and possibly an another version if you start supporting a new RDBMS). Good thing is that the entities would become simpler and Hibernate would have less chances to generate poorly performing SQL.

Comment: @MickMnemonic the model is quite complex with 10+ tables that could potentially be joined over multiple levels (things like entity->category->texts) and some data columns that can be created/added at runtime and which to some degree are modelled after the [entity abstraction pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Abstraction_Pattern) (which is considered an anti-pattern by some and which is only used for the parts that actually require it).

Comment: @MickMnemonic views might be an option for the main part of our model whose structure is static at runtime. How would you go about potential to-many relations there? Would they be modelled as array columns in some way?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement at my past employer and we noticed similarly that under smaller datasets the database was more than capable of doing it; however, there will be a tipping point where even the database will suffer.

My solution was to introduce Hibernate Search and its integration with ElasticSearch to store the search data in a NoSQL Lucene datastore, which is absolutely fast for unicode based text queries and sorting, as you've described.

This allows you to continue to use the Hibernate ORM infrastructure you already have and bake into your architecture these additoinal components with minimal effort.  The integration is seamless and certainly worth the investment, especially as your dataset continues to grow with time.

We were working with 10s of millions of rows and had absolutely no performance issues.  A query doing sorting and paging took on average less than 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Thx for the info. We actually have Hibernate Search already in place just with Lucence being used directly instead of Elastic. Would Elastic improve performance additionally or just make accessing the data easier? How do you handle updates - do you update the changed documents as a whole or only the fields that have changed (if that's possible)? I also guess the updates are handled asynchronously, aren't they?

Comment: I found using ES easier as the indexes are hosted in more of a micro service architecture than embedding Lucene directly into the application.  We also had some issues with index replication between master/slave which lead us to using ES instead.  As for updates, they're replicated to ES just like they're replicated today to Lucene.  I believe the updates aren't asynchronous but instead occur when Hibernate raises the various events that Search listens for.

Comment: Afaik Hibernate Search triggers the updates at the end of the transaction so yes they're basically synchronous by default. We encountered some problems with this though (in another project) when larger transactions required us to clear the first level cache every now and then which caused HS to choke on detached entities. Thus we introduced some asynchronous update there and hence my question (asynchronous updates also would reduce the risk of transaction rollbacks if ES/Lucene isn't available).

Comment: Perhaps but you could make sure you setup ES behind a proxy such that you guarantee that the proxy is up and you have your ES nodes running in a cluster so that there is at least one instance always up and available for redundancy purposes.

Comment: Hmm, that might reduce the risk. However, ES failures might not be a problem at all even with synchronous updates since consistency between actual data and ES might be valued quite high. I'm currently trying to have that checked by our UX experts and/or project management. :)